# remove the common elements in array based on index value

Tags: python, ruby

I have one array want to remove the duplicate value based on index

Eg: a= [1,3,4,3]

Expected array : a = [1,4,3]

Want to remove the common elements with lower index value

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) - and please don't spam tags, we currently don't know if you're asking a python or a ruby question - though at the moment you're not asking a question at all, you're only telling us that there's something you want to do. So go ahead, do it.

Comment: Are you working with Ruby or Python? there are bid differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not optimal, but since you don't seem to look for a fast algorithm, this should be enough (especially with small arrays):

```
[1,3,4,3].reverse.uniq.reverse
```

This code is for Ruby only.

Comment: It's actually not too bad. `uniq` in ruby uses a hash table, so the whole thing should be O(3N), which is still linear.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop through the list in reverse order:

```
    for index in range(len(my_list)-1,-1,-1):
        if my_list[index] in my_list[index+1:]:
            del my_list[index]
```

Comment: This looks like O(N^3) time complexity. Not very good. With O(N) additional space, it should be possible to perform this operation in O(N) time. The question did not mention efficiency constraints, so I'm just thinking out loud.

Comment: I agree with that. I kept my code as universal and easy as possible, in order to be as close as possible to the (assumed) programming skills of the thread opener.